How do I upgrade CBC Solver from 2.10.3 to 2.10.7 in PULP?
Currently I am using PuLP for an optimization problem, and default CBC MIP Solver 2.10.3 - which is the default solver. I have ran into a problem and seems like they have fixed a bug in version 2.10.7. So I need to update the solver - not the PuLP library itself, it is updated already - to the latest version. Does anyone know how to actually do that?
Thanks to anyone in advance for taking their time to answer.


Download the latest binary version of CBC (2.10.12)
Adjust your environment variables so that they include the path to the binary (.exe)
Call the solver with prob.solve(solver=pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD()) as per the pulp documentation.

Note that pulp has API's with most (all (?)) solvers (open source and commercial), and you might be better off with SCIP or HIGHS which are free and more efficient than CBC.
